# Android SDK unavialable

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-studio-flamingo

I got "Unable to access Android SDK add-on list" after Flamingo istalation. I istalled it on Windows 7 and there is NO internet conection on computer. Do I have to install SDK? I dont understand how to SDK must be istalled. Thanks for help.

I was trying istall SDK. Downloaded cmdline-tools and emulator. Put it on SDK directory but when i set SDK folder location on SDK manager it say: Target folder is neither empty nor does it point to an existing SDK installation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.